# UiTableView bug, added cell doesnt insert text needed

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hey guys i have a table view that can add and delete cells. but when i delete the only cell that comes with the app, and i try to add a new cell with the text of "Meghan Way" and the text just automatically changes it self to the original cells text which is "House 1" here is my code!

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
FacePlatesViewController * viewController = (FacePlatesViewController   
*)self.parentViewController;

[viewController addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:text.text    
forKey:@"name"]]; 

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero   
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
UIImage * myimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"check.png"];
image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:myimage];



tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    self.myTableView = tableView;


}
return cell;

}
```

this is for the save button! any help would be very appreciated:D Thanks

Comment: We need the code of FacePlatesViewController in order to help you with this at all.

Comment: I really doubt that's a bug of UITableView, as the title says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is quite messed up. I have improved it below and added comments:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero   
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }  //The if block should end here. You should set the cell's label irrespective whether the cell was nil. This is the cause of the issue you are facing.

    cell.textLabel.text = [[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];

    //You are doing nothing with the UIImage
    //UIImage * myimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"check.png"];
    //image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:myimage];


    //You should be setting the background color just once, in ViewDidLoad, not here.
    //tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //I don't see why this is required
    //self.myTableView = tableView;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: hey man sorry to bother you, but your code works like a charm, thanks so much! , but the bug is now in a different spot :O after i add the cell, the text is good, but when i switch pages and then go back, the cell is backk to the house 1 text. Do you know why this is? Is it because i must save the state of the app before leavin the page? Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Have you confirmed that the cells array has the correct values?

Comment: hmm im not sure what you mean by that... could you explain that a bit better? THanks p.s. im a N00B lol :D

Comment: i mean the array named `cells` that you have. Is it returning the correct value?

Comment: hmmm i think it is, but when i turn the page i dont know if the page is going to the original state or if the table view code is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the text labels for these cells in any kind of array or dictionary and loading them in there using the standard "cellForRowAtIndexPath?" If so, then you need to delete the dictionary / array entry in that data source to prevent it from being used again.

I can't tell for sure without seeing some more code...but it sounds like a cell recycling issue. I could be wrong...but I'd need to see more info.

Comment: yes i am i did that with a plist here.. ill update the question with cellForRow. and thanks for the help :D oh and the problem isnt with deleting the cells its with the text. The app starts out with 1 cells named "House 1" and when the user deletes this cell and adds a new cell, they are taken to another page to type the text of the new cell. and when they click the save button, the text isnt what they typed in it is still "House 1"